# Not show push notification (Firebase Cloud Message) on status bar when app is not running

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service
        

android:name=".CustomFirebaseInstanceIDService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <service
        android:name=".CustomFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

My service:

```
import android.util.Log
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage
import org.tokend.template.BuildConfig

class CustomFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
        if (remoteMessage?.data?.isNotEmpty()!!) {
            val payloadData: Map<String, String> = remoteMessage.data
            PushNotificationService.showNotification(applicationContext, payloadData["title"]!!, payloadData["body"]!!)
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        remoteMessage.notification?.let {
            val notificationTitle : String? = it.title
            val notificationBody: String? = it.body
            PushNotificationService.showNotification(applicationContext, notificationTitle!!, notificationBody!!)
        }
    }
```

And show push:

```
object PushNotificationService {
    val TAG = PushNotificationService::class.java.name
    val CHANNEL_ID = "channelId"
    val NOTIFICATON_ID = 1

    fun showNotification(context: Context, title: String, body: String) {
        val intent = Intent(context, SignInActivity::class.java).apply {
            this.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        }
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

        // Show the notification
        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context), {
            // NOTIFICATON_ID is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            this.notify(NOTIFICATON_ID, builder.build())
        })
    }
```

So:

1. when server send **data** or **notification** and application is run and **foreground** then method `onMessageReceived` success call and success show push notification  (title and body) in the status bar (on top)
2. when server send **data** or **notification** and application is run and **minimize** then method `onMessageReceived` success call and success show push notification in the status bar (on top)
3. But when server send **data** or **notification** and application is NOT RUNNING then **not call** method   `onMessageReceived` and also **not show** push notification on the status bar.

But I need to show push notification on the status bar when app is not running.

I send data message to my android device by Python script:

```
import firebase_admin, sys
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging
message = messaging.Message(
    data={
        "title": "Test data",
        "body": "Body of long test text of data test long body message for type data"
    },
    token=sys.argv[1],
)

response = messaging.send(message)
```

P.S. If I send message from Firebase console **then success show** push notification on status bar when app is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Try to only send `data` payload (without `notification` payload) it should always call `onMessageReceived`. Also try adding priority (my .js example):

```
const  payload = {
        data: {
            title: 'finalTitle',
            body: 'message',
        },
        android:{
            priority: 'high'
            },
        topic: channel
    };

    admin.messaging().send(payload)
```

Comment: Not help. Not call onMessageReceived when send only data

Comment: I've updated my answer with example payload. Your manifest already looks fine to me.